# Can I replace an interval of partitions of a BigQuery partitioned table at once?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on BigQuery tables with the Python SDK and I want to achieve something that seems doable, but can't find anything in the documentation.

I have a table **T** partitioned by date, and I have a SELECT request that computes values over the *X* last days. In **T**, I would like to replace the partitions of the *X* last days with these values, without affecting the partitions older than *X* days.

Here is how we do for replacing one partition only :

```
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.destination = dataset.table("{}${}".format(table, date.strftime("%Y%m%d")))
job_config.use_legacy_sql = False
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE

query_job = bigquery.job.QueryJob(str(uuid.uuid4()), query, client, job_config)
query_job.result()
```

I tried to go like this :

```
 job_config.destination = dataset.table(table))
```

But it truncates all partitions, even those older than *X* days.

Is there a way to do this easily ? Or do I have to loop over each partition of the interval ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve it by playing with destination table.

Not considering the cost, what you can do with SQL is

```
DELETE FROM your_ds.your_table WHERE partition_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL X DAY);
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO your_ds.your_table SELECT (...)
```

**Cost**

The first DELETE will [cost](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml_pricing_for_partitioned_tables):

> The sum of bytes processed for all the columns referenced in all partitions for the tables scanned by the query
>   + the sum of bytes for all columns in the modified or scanned partitions for the table being modified (at the time the DELETE starts).

The second INSERT INTO should cost the same as your current query.

Comment: Thank you, If I understand correctly, compared to looping over and replacing every partition, this will cost more because of the DELETE part, or the same because we pay the delete costs with write_truncate anyway ?

Comment: write_truncate should be a metadata only operation, which has no cost to "delete" (double quote because nothing really gets deleted, only metadata points to new data)